# Getting ValueError when converting a CSV to a GeoTIFF

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to convert a CSV file to a GeoTIFF file using gdal.Translate. However, I am receiving a value error. I have tried the code with a different CSV file that has the same structure but the datatypes are different. For the CSV that works the data types are float but for the CSV that isn't working the data types are ints. What i have found is that in both cases a .xyz file is produced, however, in the second case no tif is outputted and I am presented with the error.

```
df = pd.read_csv("raster.csv",sep = " ", header = None )
df.to_csv("raster.xyz", index = False, header = None, sep = " ")
demn = gdal.Translate("raster.tif", "raster.xyz", outputSRS = "EPSG:4326")

ERROR 1: Ungridded dataset: At line 38, Y spacing was 3.000000. Expected 1.000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bill/polygon-generation/tif-to-csv.py", line 22, in <module>
    demn = gdal.Translate("raster.tif", "raster.xyz", outputSRS = "EPSG:4326")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
  packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 484, in Translate
    return TranslateInternal(destName, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
  packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 4571, in TranslateInternal
    return _gdal.TranslateInternal(*args)
ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.
```

I also had a look at the line spacing on line 38 on the CSV and XYZ file and it looked exactly the same as all of the others?

```
 37 52,22,0
 38 52,23,0
 39 52,26,0
```

Comment: can you add lines 37-39

Comment: Added. I see the reason now but I dont know what I can do to fix this? The data is set I can change it

Comment: Y values are 22, 23, and 26. There is a jump of 3 from 23 to 26. GDAL was prepared to see Y value 24 in that place.

Comment: gdal.Grid for ungridded datasets